# No Method Error when using ckeditor_textarea in view - Ruby on Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ckeditor

I'm building a basic administrator area and want to include a content editor for my editors to easily edit content without knowing HTML. I've chosen to run with [CKEditor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CKEditor) and used [RubyGems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RubyGems)'s *[CKEditor](http://rubygems.org/gems/ckeditor)*.

I've followed [all the instructions](https://github.com/galetahub/rails-ckeditor) for setting this up.

I get the following error.

```
undefined method `content' for nil:NilClass

21:   </div>
22:   <div class="field">
23:     <%= f.label :content %><br />
24:     <%= ckeditor_textarea(:access_article, :content, :width => '100%', :height => '200px') %>
25:   </div>
26:   <div class="field">
27:     <%= f.label :seo_title %><br />
```

I have created an administrator area where articles can be created at domain/access/articles and created the nested resource in my routes file.

**`routes.rb` extract**

```
  namespace "access" do
    resources :pages, :articles
  end
```

I've had this working on another project, but I am not sure why it's not working this time. Where must I be doing something wrong?

Here's my form code

```
<%= form_for([:access, @access_article]) do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :title %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :title %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :permalink %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :permalink %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :content %><br />
<%= ckeditor_textarea(:access_article, :content, :width => '100%', :height => '200px') %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :seo_title %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :seo_title %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :seo_description %><br />
    <%= f.text_area :seo_description, :rows => 6 %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

If I use the standard helper, `<%= f.text_area :content %>`, I don't have any problems.

Comment: I just realized that I need to add the gem to my development group in my gemfile.

Comment: f.ckeditor_textarea ?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution: do not to use the CKEditor helper, use HTML code:

In this case field is "post[body]", and form is `f`.

```
<%= form_for([@trek,@trek.posts.build],:remote=>true) do |f| %>
    ...
    ...
<%= f.text_area :body %>

<script type="text/javascript">
    CKEDITOR.replace( 'post[body]' );
</script>

<%= ckeditor_ajax_script %>
```